# How to replace a string on HTML webpage with another string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, replace, nodelist

I need to change one string with another using JavaScript for an HTML website. So, the "AuthorList" has a nodeList with the string "Test String". I need to change all occurrences of "test string" into "new test".

I have tried a lot of different modifications of the code below. I cant seem to figure out another way without getting errors.

```
for(var i=0, num=AuthorList.length; i<num; i++){
  if(AuthorList[i] = "Test String")
  {
    string.replace("New Test")
  }
}
```

After replacing the text, I also need a way to add styles to the new string. Is there a way to do that while also changing the string?

Comment: Can you provide a mvce? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

[String.prototype.replace() Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax) needs two parameters. You also have to reassign the changed string.

**Please note:** `=` is the assignment operator, not comparison (`==`) operator. You have to use `==` in if condition.

```
for(var i=0, num=AuthorList.length; i<num; i++){
  if(AuthorList[i] == "Test String")
  {
    AuthorList[i] = string.replace("Test String", "New Test");
    //Or simply without replace()
    //AuthorList[i] = "New Test"; // This will override the previous string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
for(var i=0, num=AuthorList.length; i<num; i++){
    String oldData = "Test String";
    String newData = "New Test";
    if(AuthorList[i] == oldData){
        AuthorList[i] =newData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the element `AuthorList[i]`. Also use `==` not `=` in your conditional:

```
for (var i = 0; i < AuthorList.length; i++){
  if (AuthorList[i] == "Test String")  {
    AuthorList[i] = string.replace("Test String", "New Test");
  }
}
```

You could also do the same with `map()`:

```
AuthorList.map(e => e == "Test String" ? string.replace("Test String", "New Test") : e);
```